# ¿Cómo extraigo el valor de primera palabra de cada línea en Bash?

Tags: bash

Tengo este script

```
#!/bin/bash
cat addusuarios.txt
usuario=$1
echo $usuario
```

Y tengo el archivo addusuarios.txt que dentro tiene:

```
pedro password
```

¿Cómo hago para extraer el valor de la primera columna? En este caso, el text "pedro". Por lo que he visto en principio con $1 tendría que funcionar pero no lo termino de entender.

Answer (score 1):

Dos cosas, la primera es que puedes hacer uso del *built-in* `read` dentro de tu script.

Por ejemplo, en un archivo llamado "addusuarios.txt" con el contenido de:

```
pedro password_pedro
marco password_marco
```

Podemos usar el script.

```
#!/bin/bash

archivo='./addusuarios.txt'

while read usuario contrasena
do
    echo "usuario es: $usuario"
    echo "contrasena es: $contrasena"
done < "$archivo"
```

La segunda es que puedes hacer eso sin necesidad de un script (gracias a los buenísimos programas que se ofrecen en todas las distribuciones).

Entonces podrías utilizar varias opciones como `cut`, `sed`, `awk`, `grep`. Por ejemplo, del archivo anterior, si te das cuenta, está separado por un espacio, usemos `cut`.

```
 cut -d " " -f 1 addusuarios.txt
```

Donde `-d " "` indica que el delimitador va a ser un espacio y `-f 1` indica que va a ser el primer campo.

Podemos hacerlo con `awk`

```
awk '{print $1}' addusuarios.txt
```

Donde `awk` usa por defecto los espacios en blanco como delimitadores de campos y `$1` indica el primer campo.

También con `sed`

```
sed -r 's/^([^ ]+)[[:space:]](.*)/\1/' addusuarios.txt
```

Donde el parámetro `-r` habilita las expresiones regulares y la expresión regular que utilizo es

```
'^([^ ]+)[[:space:]](.*)'
```

que busca lo separado entre un espacio y encierra en dos grupos lo que está antes (que no contenga un espacio) y después (grupo 1 y grupo 2 respectivamente). Entonces, ya atrapados en dos grupos, retomemos el tema de la sintaxis de `sed` que es `sed 's/patron/reemplazo/` donde "s" sustituye el patrón encontrado por el reemplazo. El patrón es la expresión regular y lo reemplazado es el grupo 1, de ahí el "`\1`".

También se puede hacer con `grep`.

```
grep -Po '^.*?(?=[[:space:]])' addusuarios.txt
```

Donde `-P` habilita las expresiones regulares de *perl* y `-o` sólo imprime lo capturado por la expresión regular. La expresión regular

```
'^.*?(?=[[:space:]])'
```

busca todo lo que esté el inicio de la línea y el primer espacio, o mejor dicho "antes de un espacio".